# How To Trim the Milliseconds of timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, timestamp

I need help in converting the timestamp from

```
2017-06-01 16:52:57.530000000
```

to

```
2017-06-01 16:52:57.530
```

in databricks using SQL.

I tried

```
select 
  insert_date,
  to_timestamp(substr(insert_date,1,23) ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
from mytable
```

but it did not work.

Comment: How are those values different?

Comment: Exactly how did it “not work”? What output did you get and what were you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select insert_date, date_format(insert_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') new_date
    from mytable
```